# Need to understand on Pipeline for the issue that i am facing

Tags: salesforce

I am working on POC for my client to implement VSTS Pipelines for CICD.
While working on i have observed that my pipeline is picking all the components instead of one component.
Ex: I have 4 components and change was made only on one component, when i create a pull request for deployment to target org, ideally it should pick only the change which was modified, instead during deployment it is picking all the 4 components.

Answer (score 0):

What's being deployed is controlled by the manifest file (package.xml). You specify what you're interested in, what you want to retrieve & deploy. Sometimes you can put wildcards in it (deploy all apex classes you can find), sometimes you really have to list stuff (standard objects, reports, email templates).

So out of the box deployment is always a complete package, whether files changed or not. It's bit overkill but on the other hand what are you going to sign-off in user acceptance test phase? Not just the tickets changed, the state of whole system including regression tests.

If you don't want that - you'd need a script that cherry-picks files changed from commit X to commit Y or something. There's been some attempts to do it, check answers to [How to create Salesforce incremental package.xml automatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59442097/313628)

Next year (safe harbor blah blah blah) SF plans to release better DevOps tools: https://admin.salesforce.com/blog/2020/new-devops-center-is-awesome-for-admins